# Facebook Like Status

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, fbml, facebook-like

I'm trying to figure out the status (liked or not-liked) of the `<fb:like>` social widget on my website. If someone has already liked the page (onload) I'd like to run some code.

I've been looking at this for hours and I've been unable to get the status.

So far I have:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/2DayFM" show_faces="true" width="300">      </fb:like>

<script>
// captures the click event for the like button (want to do this, but onload)
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  // do something with response.session
  if(response == 'http://www.facebook.com/2DayFM') {
    alert('you have clicked the like button');
  }
});
</script>
```

I've tried using (and various variants)

```
FB.api({ method: 'pages.isFan', page_id: '132495853450335' }, function(response) {
  if(response == 'true') {
    // run code
  }
});
```

However I'm getting all sorts of invalid api access errors, etc.

Comment: Has anyone figured this out yet.  If so please post solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, but isn't it required to do FB.init with your Application Id , before calling other FB functions ?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.init/

Comment: I've already tried creating a temp app and using FB.init. No luck :(